# Proving $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ ~ $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

I am trying to show $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ ~ $\mathbb{R}$ using the Cantor Bernstein method. Here is my proof so far:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ be defined as for each $r_n\in\mathbb{R}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(r_n)=(r_n,0,0,...)$. Thus, we have an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. (For me, $0$ is in the natural numbers.)

Now, for the other direction, let $g:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows. Let $(r_0,r_1,...,r_n,...)\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ where $r_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $r_n=Z_n.a_{0,n}a_{1,n}a_{2,n}...$ be the unique corresponding decimal expansion where $n\in\mathbb{N}$,  $Z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $0\leq a_{n,n}\leq 9$, and the sequence does not end in infinitely many 9's.

Consider the list:

$r_0=r_n=Z_0.a_{0,0}a_{1,0}a_{2,0}...$

$r_1=r_n=Z_1.a_{0,1}a_{1,1}a_{2,1}...$

$r_2=r_n=Z_2.a_{0,2}a_{1,2}a_{2,2}...$

Then, let $r=0.a_{0,0}a_{1,0}a_{0,1}a_{0,2}a_{1,1}a_{2,0}...\in\mathbb{R}$.

So, $g((r_0,r_1,...,r_n,...))= r$.

Then, we have an injection from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. By Cantor Bernstein Theorem, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ ~ $\mathbb{R}$.

Does this proof work or how can I modify/improve it?

Comment: Hi, what you mean by $r_n$?

Comment: @sti9111 Okay, I defined it.

Comment: If you look around, you can probably find a more general proof of the fact, that if $X$ is an infinite set and $n$ is a natural number, then $X^n \simeq X$, and then adapt the proof to this situation.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Okay, but does what I have here not work then?

Comment: A nit:  you need to biject $\Bbb R$ with $(0,1)$ because you have not dealt with numbers before the decimal point.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am not sure what you mean? Would it be best then to do an injection from $(0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ instead since we know $\mathbb{R}$~$(0,1)$?

Comment: Just that your work only deals with numbers to the right of the decimal point.  There are lots of numbers in $\Bbb R$ that have digits to the left of the point.  We know $\Bbb R$ is equinumerous with $(0,1)$ so that is not a problem.  You can just chain your favorite bijection to get to $(0,1)$, then go to $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$, then use the inverse bijection to get $\Bbb {R^N}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, I think I see the issue but I am not clear on how to fix this. Why do we need the bijection in this case if we just chose to use $(0,1)$ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, for the first direction you want to express the following, given $r\in\mathbb{R},$ this have the form $a_0,a_1a_2\dots$ where every $a_i$ is a digit, then we can define $f(r)=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,\dots)$

the second part is o.k

Comment: I see, so you are turning an element in $\mathbb{R}$ into a sequence of its decimal expansion?

Comment: Yes!!! that´s the idea.

Comment: Okay, but then does what I have not work for that direction?

Comment: But we have to take care with numbers as 0.99999999.... and 1.0000000...,

Comment: I said it does not end in infinitely many 9s.

Comment: the firts direction works, I only want to give a proof using an idea to build both functions. The second direction I don´t understand what you did.

Comment: Not, your o.k, that´s the cantor diagonal idea. is. ok

Comment: Okay, then the second part works? What do you not understand so I can clarify.

Comment: I only was confused with the notation, but is o.k.

Comment: Oh okay, but yes I basically did the Cantor Diagonalization to create an element in $\mathbb{R}$.