# Are $\Bbb{R\times R}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ equinumerous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, axiom-of-choice

> Prove that the sets $\Bbb{R\times R}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are equinumerous, without $\mathsf{AC}$.

(The solutions in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551606/proving-mathbbr-mathbbn-mathbbr), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131432/proof-that-mathbbr2-cong-mathbbr?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3826729/mapping-from-0-1-times-0-1-to-0-1?rq=1) posts are a bit more complicated, so I'm trying a different approach).

**My attempt:** As $\Bbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are equinumerous, and as there is an obvious injection $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R\times R}$, by using using Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem, it is sufficient to find an injection $(0,1)\times (0,1)\to(0,1)$. For an ordered pair $\langle r,s\rangle$ of reals between $0$ and $1$, let
$$
r=0.r_1 r_2 \ldots r_n\ldots
\\
s=0.s_1 s_2 \ldots s_n\ldots
$$
be *some* decimal expansion of them. Send $\langle r,s\rangle$ to the number defined by
$$
0.r_1 s_1 0 r_2 s_2 0 \ldots r_n s_n 0\ldots
$$

This number must have a unique decimal expansion, as it cannot have any infinite series of nines in it. As we can send each real of form $0.a_1 a_2 0 a_3 a_4 0\ldots$ to the two reals $0.a_1 a_3 a_5 \ldots$ and $0.a_2 a_4 a_6 \ldots$, the described function must be one-to-one.

Is this solution OK?

**Edit:** There's a problem with the fact that $r$ and $s$ in general might not have a unique decimal expansion. We can overcome this problem by excluding from $(0,1)$ the set of numbers that have a decimal expansion with almost all digits being nines. That set is obviously countable.

Comment: @ssp thank you, I edited the post.

Comment: If either $r$ or $s$ has a nonunique representation, then just use the one with infinitely many zeroes (or alternatively, infinitely many nines) so that the injection is well-defined.

Comment: "That set is obviously countable." Doesn't this involve AC?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think $\omega^*= \omega^{<\omega}$, the set of finite sequences of natural numbers, is countable (without using $\mathsf{AC}$): send each finite series $n_1 , \ldots , n_k$ to $p_1 ^{n_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k}$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime. This is an injection into $\omega$, so by Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein, $|\omega^*| = \aleph_0$. There's a clear bijection between numbers in $(0,1)$ with almost all digits being $9$ to $\omega^*$ by sending such real to the sequence ending with the last non-$9$ digit. Right?